# How can I list the products from a category where each supplier occoures at least once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table there are products in different categories from different suppliers. How can I list the products from a category where each supplier occurs at least once?

For example:

```
select VendorName, count(*) as ItemsInElectronics
from product
where ProductCategorie = 'Electronics'
group by VendorName
```

| VendorName | ItemsInElectronics |
| --- | --- |
| company1 | 14 |
| company2 | 145 |
| company3 | 25 |
| company4 | 3 |
| company5 | 543 |
| company6 | 37 |
| company7 | 88 |
| company8 | 172 |
| company9 | 249 |
| company10 | 47 |

This is my current SQL statement to list the products in category Electronics

```
SELECT TOP(16) VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory
FROM [dbo].[Product]
WHERE ProductCategory = 'Electronics'
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

| VendorName | ProductTitle | ProductCategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company1 | Staubsauger | Electronics |
| company2 | Lenovo ThinkStation | Electronics |
| company3 | AMD Ryzen 7 5700G | Electronics |
| company2 | Digittrade HS256 S3 | Electronics |
| company4 | Kaffeemaschine Delonghi | Electronics |
| company1 | NanoCell Fernseher LG | Electronics |
| company4 | H. Koenig Handstaubsauger | Electronics |
| company1 | Wäschetrockner CANDY 8 kg | Electronics |
| company5 | Kühl-/Gefrierkombination, | Electronics |
| company6 | Asus ExpertBook B1500CEAE | Electronics |
| company7 | HP M01-F1507nz (Intel Core i5 | Electronics |
| company2 | honor Notebook MagicBook 14 | Electronics |
| company2 | WD My Passport 1 TB Externe | Electronics |
| company5 | Wasserkocher »Inox 2822CH1« | Electronics |
| company1 | Smartphone überholt APPLE | Electronics |
| company2 | Seagate One Touch Portable 5 TB Electronics |  |

How can I set it up so that at least one product from each vendor is visible?

Comment: Not sure I follow. What happens when you have more than 16 vendors? E.g. what does the `TOP (16)` actually represent?

Comment: At least one product from each vendor in the result? Well, `select * from product where productcategory = 'Electronics'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this, but it doesn't take into account what you want to do if there are more than 16 vendors:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY VendorName ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
  FROM dbo.Product
  WHERE ProductCategory = 'Electronics'
)
-- make sure we get one row from each vendor:
SELECT VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory
       FROM src WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
-- then if we want 16 rows total, take random rows from remainder:
SELECT TOP (16-(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VendorName) FROM src)) 
       VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory 
       FROM src WHERE rn > 1;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea550f9ed336f642d6dd758523695fad)

If the `TOP (16)` has significance or you have requirements that differ if there are more than 16 vendors, you need to explain. (Here's [one way you could deal with > 16 vendors](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce2a6c9e9ed3dca754eff1b390b4db63) and still get only one row per vendor.)

With the updated comment that you want more even distribution across vendors, you can do this slightly easier. This will return "chunks" of random products from each vendor, randomized within each chunk (so you might see products from company 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, then 2, 5, 4, 1, 3, and so on):

```
DECLARE @top tinyint = 24;

;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY VendorName ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
  FROM dbo.Product
  WHERE ProductCategory = 'Electronics'
)
SELECT TOP (@top) VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory
FROM src ORDER BY rn, NEWID();
```

While this one will return as even an overall distribution as possible, but more randomized (so you might see products from company 1, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, etc.):

```
DECLARE @top tinyint = 24;

;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY VendorName ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
  FROM dbo.Product
  WHERE ProductCategory = 'Electronics'
)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP (@top) VendorName, ProductTitle, ProductCategory
FROM src ORDER BY rn) x ORDER BY NEWID();
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d24d257d337d3437f19b28e6986dede4)

Comment: hi Aaron
thank you for your efforts and nice example
this partially solves my problem.

Comment: @Nida Cool, does your question only include part of your problem? Why?

Comment: after the products from all 5 suppliers are listed once each, then (remaining 11 products) only products from company1 are listed.
How can I solve it that all 5 occur multiple times up to 16 or as an example 24 products?
see here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84a6ed04b572b1ee5c2050444d81b4d2

Comment: @Nida still not sure I follow, you want an equal number of products from each company until you hit 16 or 24 total? What happens if one company only has one or two products?

Comment: yes exactly. Companys have several products

Comment: @Nida You should change the question then because originally your requirement is interpreted as "just show me each company at least once, then the rest of the 16 doesn't matter."

Comment: wau this was is perfect Aaron.
thank you so very much for your help and efforts